# MapView crashing once adding more pins to mapview

Tags: ios6

How to remove zoom from mapView if user zoom its on button click.

for (id annotation in annotations)
        {

```
        MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
    MKMapRect zoomRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0.0, 0.0);
    [m_mapView setVisibleMapRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`MKMapRectMake` cant have 0,0 in rect's width height. once u can make it to a value your crashing will stop

Comment: Thanks for response But what is my requirement once mapView loaded and pins draw over mapview i have more button to add more pins. So in this case if user did zoonin and hit more button my mapview crashing. so that i want to check if user did zoomin first i have to undo all zoom then i need to add pins. How do i do this.